# MVC 4 Web API NullException Error (Noobie)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ldap, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on my first MVC 4 app, following the MVC First Web API Tutorial on Asp.net.  I've left the names the same, but changed the model and controller code. Here's my model:

```
public class Product
{
    public string SID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string givenName { get; set; }
    public string sn { get; set; }
    public string mail { get; set; }
    public string telephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string otherMobile { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public DateTime whenChanged { get; set; }
}

public class ProductModel
{
    public ProductModel()
    {
        ProductList = new List<Product>();
    }
    public IList<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my APIcontroller:

```
 public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    ProductModel products = new ProductModel();

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAD()
    {
        DirectoryEntry domainRoot = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP_server);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchStr);
        SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();
        foreach (SearchResult srchResult in results)
        {
            DirectoryEntry dirEntry = srchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
            if (dirEntry.Properties["givenName"].Value != null && dirEntry.Properties["sn"].Value != null && !dirEntry.Parent.Name.Contains("Terminated"))
            {
                products.ProductList.Add(new Product()
                {
                    SID = dirEntry.Properties["sid"].Value.ToString(),
                    name = dirEntry.Properties["name"].Value.ToString(),
                    givenName = dirEntry.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString(),
                    sn = dirEntry.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString(),
                    mail = dirEntry.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString(),
                    telephoneNumber = dirEntry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString(),
                    mobile = dirEntry.Properties["mobile"].Value.ToString(),
                    otherMobile = dirEntry.Properties["otherMobile"].Value.ToString(),
                    title = dirEntry.Properties["title"].Value.ToString(),
                    Manager = dirEntry.Properties["Manager"].Value.ToString(),
                    whenChanged = Convert.ToDateTime(dirEntry.Properties["whenChanged"].Value.ToString()),
                });
            }
        }
        return products.ProductList;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the NullException on 'products.ProductList.Add(new Product()', am I missing something simple?  Please forgive my coding, as I'm just trying to get this up and running, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.  'sid' is not the correct property name from AD, it is 'objectSid', thus always returning a null.  I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

the problem mostly likely is dealing with dirEntry, not Web API itself. rather than introduce LDAP into this, just create a bunch of dummy products to return.

FYI... there is also a memory leak issue with the use of LDAP objects. They need to be properly disposed of, both along the happy path and if an exception is thrown.